# Yii2 and git ignore files

Tags: git, svn, yii2, vendor

I have recently switched from `svn` to `git` and i'm a little bit confused.

In the yii2 framework, there are many `.gitignore` files and i understand the use of these files. but im a bit confused of why is the `vendor` directory ignored.

The files in there are needed on both my development and production environment.

I used to commit the files in there when using `svn`, but was i doing it wrong? What is the correct way to do it if i am ignoring the `vendor` dir.

Do i need to run `composer update` on both the environment everytime i do a push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said by @chris--- it is just a recommandation after all and it is up to you to choose to upload and maintain vendor libraries or not. To get an idea on how it works, go to `composer.json` inside your app and you'll see something like this :

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
    "yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-swiftmailer": "*"
},
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "*",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "*"
},
```

Where you can edit and a set the specific version of any library if needed. Now taking this line :

```
"yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap": "*"
```

Each time you do `composer update` Composer will just get its repo from **packagist.org** (*see it [here](https://packagist.org/packages/yiisoft/yii2-bootstrap)*), will install the last stable version found (that what `"*"` means) then will solve its dependencies which can be seen inside `\vendor\yiisoft\yii2-bootsrap\composer.json` :

```
"require": {
    "yiisoft/yii2": ">=2.0.6",
    "bower-asset/bootstrap": "3.3.* | 3.2.* | 3.1.*"
},
```

The last line will garante the installation of the last stable version of **Twitter Bootstrap 3.3.x**.

Those are the exact libraries with their exact versions downloaded after requesting [packagist.org](https://packagist.org/) and saved to the vendor folder each time you do a `composer update` from any machine. If you upload **twitter bootstrap 3.3.2** along with your project as example and a team member download it back without having to do `composer update` then he may find himself stuck in an issue that suppose to be fixed in version **3.3.3** and where he would never needed to know about if he just made the update.

This is what Composer Team are saying to answer the question : [Should I commit the dependencies in my vendor directory?](https://github.com/composer/composer/blob/master/doc/faqs/should-i-commit-the-dependencies-in-my-vendor-directory.md) :

> The general recommendation is no...
>
> ...While it can be tempting to commit it in some environment, it leads to
>   a few problems:
>
> - Large VCS repository size and diffs when you update code.
> - Duplication of the history of all your dependencies in your own VCS.
> - Adding dependencies installed via git to a git repo will show them as    submodules. This is problematic because they are not real
>     submodules,    and you will run into issues.

Also think on how big the extra disk space that should be allocated to **github.com** if every project had to be uploaded with its vendors. And think on how many exact same copy of twitter bootstrap could be found there.

Answer (score 3):

That's right. Usually you don't commit the vendor stuff because that's 3rd party code in there which is under version control elsewhere. You should use composer to handle updating the vendor specific code. That means everytime you deploy the app you should run a `composer update`, unless you already have all your vendor code and there wasn't any updates to the stuff you need.

Comment: Ok i understand your point, but still there are some confusion for me. Assume i am going to start a new project, where do i start it? on my server (procuction) or local machine (development), then push it to my git.. Now once everything is setup, and lets say i develop a module which has composer dependencies, when i push it to prod, i would have to do a composer update there which would place the dependencies there. but if i worked for a long time on my module and there has been an update to the dependencies but i didnt update my local composer, my server will have a different version, right?

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understand you correctly, but both composer.json (dev & prod) should be the same. This is why you have it under version control too. So after doing a `composer update` both the dev and prod machines should have the same version.
Besides that, it is just a recommandation. It is totally fine to have the vendor folder under version control, if you are aware of it. But code there might get overwritten when doing a composer update.